# How to create a list of names, excluding missing values?

Tags: python, string, formatting, format

I have been the getting results:

Name: Hemingway, Ernest

Name: Madonna,

Name: , Voltaire

Name: ,

It seems as though the code is skipping all of my if and elif statements, I'm new to this so any help would be appreciated. Any explanation to my mistakes would be really beneficial.

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
        # code goes here
        string = ("Name: " + last_name + ", " + first_name)
        if first_name==0 and last_name==1:
            print ("Name: " + last_name)
        elif first_name==1 and last_name==0:
                print ("Name: " + first_name)
        elif first_name==0 and last_name==0:
            print ("")
        else:
            return string  
    ''''
    print(format_name("Ernest", "Hemingway"))
    # Should return the string "Name: Hemingway, Ernest"
    
    print(format_name("", "Madonna"))
    # Should return the string "Name: Madonna"
    
    print(format_name("Voltaire", ""))
    # Should return the string "Name: Voltaire"
    
    print(format_name("", ""))
    # Should return an empty string
''''
```

Comment: The answers here are nice clean solutions to the problem. In terms of why your code is not working, comparing a string and a boolean integer will always return false in python. I think the best way to go about this using your would be to compare your names to empty strings eg. `if last_name == "":`. You could also compare the lengths of the strings, so look for strings of zero length

Comment: @Immot makes good points. There's another issue which is that the first three blocks (the onees before `else`) `print` then return nothing (`None`) while the `else` `return`s the empty string. This is a bit of an odd behavior. Normally, one would want _either_ to print (a string, including an empty one) and return `None` _or_ return the relevant string.

Answer (score 2):

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    out = last_name + ", " + first_name
    out = out.strip(", ") 
    if not out:
        return ''
    return "Name: " + out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    if last_name:                              # if last isn't ""
        if first_name:                             # if first isn't ""
            return f"Name: {last_name}, {first_name}"     
        return f"Name: {last_name}"                
     return f"Name: {first_name}" if first else ""
```

Output

```
Name: Hemingway, Ernest
Name: Madonna
Name: Voltaire
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter a list for false-y type values and join the results. Then you can return a conditional.

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    name = ", ".join(filter(None, [last_name, first_name]))
    return f"Name: {name}" if name else ""
```

With assignment operator this can be a oneliner:

```
def format_name(first_name, last_name):
    return f"Name: {n}" if (n := ", ".join(filter(None, [last_name, first_name]))) else ""
```